EXCEL randbetween- text representation - clarification
I have made a simple coin toss in EXCEL, and understands what the formula does and what the outcome may be.
=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;1);"""HEAD"";;""TAILS""")

Can someone explain what all the double/triple qoutes does?
Below would be a more logical way to do it for me
=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;1);"HEAD";"TAILS")

Need an explanation for a formula.

I find =IF(RANDBETWEEN(0;1);"HEAD";"TAILS") the most logical.

TEXT() only has 2 arguments, 'value' and 'format'; so your more logical way will throw an error. The triple/double quotes will assing either 'head' or 'tails' to 0 and 1. I'm unsure how though, but it works.

I think this explains it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68 . "HEAD" is for positive numbers, "TAILS" is for zeros. Your number format code is "HEAD";;"TAILS". And then when you put "HEAD";;"TAILS" inside a pair of double quotes " ", you need to change the inner double quotes to "" "". ie. """HEAD"";;""TAILS"""

Shouldn't the formula be:  =CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;2);"Head";"Tails").... I mean, the original formula posted works but to me CHOOSE just seems a better approach.  Just my viewpoint though. :)

This is the logic of the TEXT function.

Argument 1: RANDBETWEEN returns either 0 or 1.
Argument 2: A String of formatting the input according to the cell format custom rules for positive,negative and zero values.
Since it must be a string the first and last quote means that this is a string. Within it all quotes must be doubled.

